# i downloaded bootstrap 5 and jquery 3.6,the issue is that when i embed them the dropdown button is not working is there anything missing in my code?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

**this is my code:**  i downloaded bootstrap 5 and jquery 3.6,the issue is that when i embed them the dropdown button is not working is there anything missing in my code?

```
<head>
    <title>
        Restaurant
    </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown button
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="./bootstrap-5.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    
</body>"
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean? What do you want to happen? What actually does happen? What errors are produced along the way?

Comment: when i click on dropdown button nothing appears below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your `jquery`, `popper` before `bootstrap`. A working example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- css --> 
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did it, still not working!

Comment: @BilalAwada I have updated the answer with working example, add popper also

Comment: thank you its working, but the fact is that i need to download them locally, is there any way to reach this?

Comment: Yes, you can do what your doing at the moment. But use the links from the answer to download the assets and use relative path in the html